# not getting entries from text boxes php

Tags: php

For the last couple of days I have been having an issue where my PHP code will not get the text from a form text box that has worked for 7 or 8 years. Has anyone else has this issue or is there something that may need to be running that isn't?

My PHP form is a username textbox and password textbox and submit button

this is the code that is going to the die because the username isn't being set:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
} else {
    die('User is blank'); //$username = "";
}
```

this error is going to my error_log

**PHP Warning:  mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 4 in /home/**

I know I know... no mysqli

form html:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return vloginform(this);" 
action="https://www..com/php_include/processlogin.php" 
name="loginform">
<div id="pleft">
<div class="uandp">Username: </div><div class="inputbox"><input type="text" 
name="username" maxlength="30" class="buttonsboxes" style="width: 180px;" />
</div>
<div class="uandp">Password: </div><div class="inputbox"><input 
type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" class="buttonsboxes" 
style="width: 180px;" /></div>
</div>
<div id="pright">
<p><input class="buttonsboxes" type="submit" value="login" name="submit" 
id="submit" /><input class="buttonsboxes" type="reset" value="reset" 
name="reset" id="reset" /></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You should show us your client code as well, let us know how the data is getting to the php web service.

Comment: Can you show us where you set the session and where you get the error? Because we cannot tell anything from the code you have given us.

Comment: The Unholy Programmer  -  everything is on the server side.

Comment: No... show us your form dude.

Comment: Spectarion   -   something like that???

Comment: based on the answers below and your responses, there is code you're not showing us.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are fetching the records but using `mysql_fetch_array` instead of manually fetching every column value will fix this issue. Try analysing the result before fetching it. If result is empty, skip fetching.

Something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename");
if (!$result || !mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    die('No records.');
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: I might look into that once I get the username to go to the code again. I am going to update a lot of the code to mysqli probably too

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use $_REQUEST variable instead of $_SESSION variable because whenever the data is transferred from a form to php page, it is transferred in $_REQUEST variable not in $_SESSION variable.
Use can do something like:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['username'])) {
    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
} else {
    die('User is blank'); //$username = "";
}
```

**UPDATE**

As per your code, you are using post method to send the data, so you should you $_POST variable to get the data from the form:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

and you can check whether it is empty or not by writing following line of code:

```
if ($username == null) {
    die('User is blank'); // if username = "", this line will be executed
} else {
    // do the required task...
}
```

I just tried the function - `isset($_REQUEST['username'])` and `isset($_POST['username'])` also, but it is not giving the desired result. But I have got above code to work.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: I am getting the same thing with $_REQUEST. this is the only code before that <?php session_start();

Comment: I changed it to $_POST but I am still not getting anything in 'username'. So essentially my script dies because username is empty

Comment: Then I'm not sure about that. But when I tested the above code, it worked fine for me.

Comment: Right. I'm missing something important. The variables from the 2 html text boxes aren't getting passed to the php scripts.

Comment: Please check out your link provided in the 'action' attribute in your form tag. Make sure that link is correct. Maybe that's the reason for the problem.

Comment: I omitted that for use on here. That is intact in my actual code.

Comment: Oh...okay. Then the problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the tag **required** in the textbox or if you are using the $_POST VARIABLE.

POST:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
} else {
  die('User is blank'); //$username = "";
}
```